# Easy way to add not impemented stub of all abstract members

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Silly question - I'm implementing Custom Membership and Role Providers for an ASP.NET MVC application that extend classes MembershipProvider and RoleProvider respectively. In the development phase I may only have a few routines written before I begin my initial unit testing. When I compile I get a long list of errors that "class X does not implement inherited abstract member member y". Is there any way to add all override routines and have them throw a notImplementedException for all virtual members without having to individually go through the list and add each virtual member one at a time?

Comment: You can do it in Visual studio as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In visual studio you should be able to type in the MyClass : IMyInterface and then left click on the IMyInterface and see a little blue box.  Mouse over the little blue box and you should have Implement IMyInterface or Explicitly implement IMyInterface as options.  Click on Implement IMyInterface and it will create all the necessary method stubs.

(I think I also have the PowerTools extension http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef installed, so this may be a feature from that, I'm not sure).

But I find a way to have a much more "optional" kind of behavior is to have a base class implement the interface with all of the empty stubs, and then subclasses can override on an opt-in basis, making for way less clutter.  But because of the limitations on single inheritance you may not be able to do that.

Comment: Normal visually studio lets you rightclik and there should be an option like 'implement abtsract class'

Answer (score 3):

There are some tools that do this for you. I personally love and use Resharper by Jetbrains

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

There may be others as well.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Rhino mocks.  You can get a stub object which has trivial implementations of an abstract class.